# Error while copying local file to k8s container

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to copy a jar file to specific pod's container by executing below command.

`kubectl cp local_policy.jar  podname:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/security`.

I am getting below error.

```
rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"tar\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tar binary is necessary to run cp. It is in the help page of kubectl cp:

```
kubectl cp --help
Copy files and directories to and from containers.

Examples:
  # !!!Important Note!!!
  # Requires that the 'tar' binary is present in your container
  # image.  If 'tar' is not present, 'kubectl cp' will fail.
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail about tar and how can i copy this inside pod

Comment: tar is a binary (also a file format) for compressing and expanding files. It is installed by default in most operating systems. Which docker image are you using?

Comment: Has it solve the problem? If you need help installing tar inside your docker image tell me

Answer (score 1):

Just install `tar` binary in the container to/from which you want to copy files. This will allow the kubectl command to copy files from your local machine to the target container. 
On Amazon linux you can install it via `yum`

```
yum install tar
```